# How to change the order of checkout from fields in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've used this snippet to add custom field in woocommerce checkout form. But the field is added to the last portion. I need the field to be displayed after the phone field. As well as it must be an required field

```
/*** Add custom field to the checkout page ***/
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'custom_checkout_field');

function custom_checkout_field($checkout) {
    woocommerce_form_field('billing_phone', array(
    'type' => 'number',
    'class' => array(
        'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ),
        'label' => __('Phone 2'),
        'placeholder' => __(''),
    ),
    $checkout->get_value('billing_phone'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

here is the portion where the custom field has been added

[image]

the custom field must be added below this phone field

[image]

what i've to change here to solve this issue. waiting for response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added the code to "woocommerce_after_order_notes" action. And it does it. You have to change it to "woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form".
Here's [Post from businessbloomer](https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-checkout-page/) that explains where the positions are.

And here is the fixed code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'custom_checkout_field');
// for the shipping form
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_shiiping_form', 'custom_checkout_field');


function custom_checkout_field($checkout) {
    woocommerce_form_field('billing_phone', array(
    'type' => 'number',
    'class' => array(
        'my-field-class form-row-wide'
        ),
        'label' => __('Phone 2'),
        'placeholder' => __(''),
    ),
    $checkout->get_value('billing_phone'));
    echo '</div>';
}
```

with best regards